My XAML and c# don't find each other anymore
I have a really weird problem.
In all my user controls, IntializeComponents() has a red squiggly.
I cannot find any named XAML components in the code behind.
Everything that is red but I already typed earlier still works.
Everything new I type, doesn't work. I can't ignore the squigglies.
I'm not sure when the problem started. I read about namespace conflicts, but I didn't refactor anything.
My teacher (I'm still learning) told me in the past that if you use binding. You should build often to keep references. But again I didn't really change XAML today.
Any ideas what I have to do here?

Usually removing the bin and obj folders, then rebuilding the solution should solve the issue

you are a hero.

Removing the Bin and obj folder of the solution worked.
ty Sancho
